# Eclipse device not launching

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been working with eclipse, made multiple runs when suddenly I get this error:

```
[2014-05-26 23:06:05 - pokerOriginal] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
[2014-05-26 23:06:05 - pokerOriginal] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-05-26 23:06:05 - pokerOriginal] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat:

```
05-26 17:13:59.984: E/memtrack(1032): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or
directory)
05-26 17:13:59.984: E/android.os.Debug(1032): failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-26 17:14:00.504: E/PackageManager(382): Failed to bind to media container service
```

It was working, now suddenly it doesn't. I closed eclipse and started it again, same result. I also rebooted, it didn't help either. Something like this had already happened, it sort of got fixed by itself, but I had to work on a friend's computer until it did.
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to delete the existing AVD and create the new one. Just Reboot the system, re-start the Eclipse and Re-launch the AVD. Sometimes, if you stress too much on Eclipse, it behaves unlike.

To support you more, I've created PNG files to guide you better for creating AVDs which I'm attaching here...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please accept my response as 'useful answer' and vote up by clicking on the Up arrow on my response.

Comment: There may be a rule for a new user to get the reputation of at least 10+ and only then it allows I think. Please try the same after you reach that set milestone :>). Meanwhile, welcome to the android programming and wishing you the good luck !

Comment: Thank you! :) I will vote up as soon as I reach the required reputation